# How to handle selection with large amounts of data in NatTable

Tags: nattable

When using the NatTable with a selection layer, if I have huge amounts (1million+) columns of data, selecting a row will take extremely long amounts of time (20 seconds+) or will outright crash my application. Is there a better way to handle selection of large amounts of data or maybe a way to select the entire amount but only visually show the amount of showing columns as selected and updating that as the table is scrolled?

Comment: Are you now talking about selecting one row or all rows in your NatTable? That is not clear from your question.

Comment: Either will cause the problem to occur. It happens when selecting any amount of incredibly large data, i.e. selecting one row with 1 million+ columns will trigger it, as well as then selecting multiple rows that each have the million+ columns.

Comment: What selection model do you use?

Comment: I call the two parameter constructor so it seems that I'm passing 'null' for the ISelectionModel

Comment: So you use the default SelectionModel. How do you select the row? Via row header or in some other way? And what is your use case? Do you need to support all kinds of selections (cell, row, column) or only row selections? BTW what use case do you have for one million columns?

Comment: I select the row via the row header.  I need to support all kinds of selections, however the only time it struggles is with row selection (as I assume it does some code for each item in the row). I use it for historical data so it easily gets into the millions of columns.

Comment: Looks like you found a performance leak. Could you please create a ticket via https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=NatTable

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is really a performance leak in NatTable. And interestingly it exists in that form for a long time and nobody has seen this until now.

I created a ticket [1] and work on a fix.

Until that you could try to remove or replace the "bad guys" from your composition. If that is not possible, you need to wait for the fix.

- `ColumnReorderLayer`: if you don't need column reorder support, remove it from your layer stack (when talking about millions of columns, I suppose reordering is not a required feature)
- `ColumnHideShowLayer`: if you don't need to support hiding columns, remove it from your layer stack. Not sure if you need it for your use case of showing millions of columns.
- `SelectionModel`: I don't know your data model, but maybe the `PreserveSelectionModel` performs slightly better at the moment. Or have a look at the proposed fix attached to the ticket (once it is uploaded) and use a local version of that fix in your environment by creating a custom `ISelectionModel` implementation based on the fix.

[1] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509685